# How to set selected value of external item picker

Tags: external-list, item

I have developed a custom edit form with an external item picker as application page in visual studio. The picker is populated with data using the following method.

```
private ItemPickerExtendedData GetExtendedData(string lobInstanceName, string entityName, string entityNamespace, string titleFieldName,
        string secondaryColumnName)
    {
        ItemPickerExtendedData data = new ItemPickerExtendedData 
        {   
            SystemInstanceName = lobInstanceName,
            EntityName = entityName,
            EntityNamespace = entityNamespace,
            PrimaryColumnName = titleFieldName
        };

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(secondaryColumnName))
            data.SetSecondaryColumnNames(new[] { secondaryColumnName });

        return data;           
    }
```

The picker should now display in it´s textfield the foreign item that is referenced by the currently edited item. E.g., if I edit a bill that is connected with a customer, I should see the customer that has currently been associated with the bill and saved as foreign key in the database.